# face like button replacing actual og:url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I seem to be missing something very important in implementing Facebook like buttons to my article based website.

Everything seems to be configured correctly according to the Facebook debugger. But when I actually try to "like" a post, the true url get's replaced with the facebook url. For example, I am liking a post http://www.mysite.com/post/1 , for some reason mysite is being replaced with "facebook", so I end of liking http://www.facebook.com/post/1 . That is how it is showing up both when you hit the like in the modal and on my facebook wall.

Here are my tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://www.mysite.com/posts/{$post->id}" ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/media/logo.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXXXXX"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo text::limit_words($post->content, 20, '...'); ?>"/>
```

All the urls are showing correct in the Linter, so I can't figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a relative URL in the data-href="URL" in your actual LIKE button code in the page? e.g. I use the facebook like button code as follows, using the og tags set up like you have above:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo "http://www.mysite.com/posts/{$post->id}" ?>">        data-send="false" data-count="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="47" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I was passing a relative url as the data-href attribute